# Getting error "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" after executing poetry install command in terminal in python project

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python project and after creating virtual environment in it. I have executed `pip install poetry`, after that when I execute `poetry install` to install all dependencies from `pyproject.toml` file I get the error `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.My current python version is 3.8.0. If anyone know the solution for it do let me know.

[Terminal Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVcyJ.png)

Comment: What happens if you try using an actual command line instead of your IDE? Also, if your current Python version is 3.8, why did you tag the question as `python-2.7`?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Are you _really_ using Python 2.7? I don't expect that to work with Poetry.